# Error: GetImaePath Doesnot exist in current context

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, data-binding

I am binding the gridview to GetImagePath to show the Image at the edit and delete button.
as :

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibEdit" runat="server" CommandName="EditItem" CausesValidation="false" ImageUrl='<%#GetImagePath("edit.gif")%>' 
                    ToolTip="Edit Item" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ibDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="ibDelete_Click" ImageUrl='<%#GetImagePath("action_delete.gif")%>'
                    ToolTip="Delete Item" />
            </ItemTemplate>
```

but when i run, it shows me the following error
`GetImaePath Doesnot exist in current context` 
what possible code i am missing or if there are any error. thanks for any assistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a C# function defined in code behind (.cs) or in .aspx code block with the name GetImagePath(string image)

```
public string GetImagePath(string image)
{
  // return full image path
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir. forgot declare this function